# How to establish connection between raspberry pi and android?

Tags: android

I need to sent my sensor data's to android device and i need to control actuators from my Android

Comment: Everyone want so many things. Only those who try succeed. In short where is the code you tried?

Comment: You have to create a local server using that connect pi and android device to this local network and send data using web service or other option is you can use socket programming to send data like WiFi chat.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry pi 3 have embedded wifi module, so you can easily connect it with android via bluetooth, wifi direct or wifi hotspot. If you have a older version of raspberry you have to connect it by lan cable and to write a service on raspberry which will receive the data from android client. Also you can use side services to sync the data between your phone and IOT device, for example you can use google drive or mail.